# R/Shiny: Group by and Summarise on column selected in dropdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am very new to R and Shiny, so I apologize in advance if this is too basic.

I am trying to render a bar graph where I select the X and Y off dropdowns. I need to aggregate by average values of Y for each X I choose. When I ran the below code, I got an error stating "Column 'y' not found". I cannot pass the actual column name selected as that can change. How do I solve this issue?

```
        output$MultivariatePlot <- renderPlotly({
      if (input$Apply > 0){
        isolate({
          req(data$Policies)
          
          x <- input$MultivariateX
          y <- input$MultivariateY
          
          rv$g <- data$Policies %>%
            group_by(y) %>% summarise(y = mean(y)) %>%
            ggplot2::ggplot(aes_(x = sym(x), y = sym(y))) +
            # ggplot2::stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
            ggplot2::geom_bar(stat='identity') +
            ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = rara::ColorSelect(2)) +
            ggplot2::theme_classic() +
            ggplot2::theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'gray80', linetype = 'longdash', size = 0.3)) +
            ggplot2::labs(title = paste('Comparison Between', x, 'and', y))
        })
```

Comment: You can pass `!!sym(y)`: the !! tells `group_by` to treat it as a symbol. Note that you're going to have the same issue with `summarize(y = mean(y))`, but that can be fixed. But first, are you sure you wanted to group by `y`, not by `x`? (Given that you're taking the mean of y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `!!sym(x)` in places that you would normally use the symbol version of `x`, and `!!sym(y)` in places where you would normally use the symbol version of `y`.

This turns your code into the following:

```
rv$g <- data$Policies %>%
  group_by(!!sym(x)) %>%
  summarise(!!sym(y) := mean(!!sym(y))) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = !!sym(x), y = !!sym(y))) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  # etc
```

There's one last complication in there, which is that you had to use `:=` instead of `=` when it's to the right of a `sym()`. (Also note that `aes_` isn't usually recommended anymore, so I used `x = !!sym(x)` in regular `aes()`, and `geom_col()` is a shortcut for `ggplot2::geom_bar(stat='identity')`).

Here's a reproducible example of the above, which takes two strings for `x` and `y` and aggregates + plots them:

```
x <- "cyl"
y <- "mpg"

mtcars %>%
  group_by(!!sym(x)) %>%
  summarise(!!sym(y) := mean(!!sym(y))) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = !!sym(x), y = !!sym(y))) +
  ggplot2::geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I select `summarise(!!sym(y) := mean(!!sym(y)))`, it gives me an invalid argument error. I skipped the `!!` and it worked.